# Make a type behave like an 'object' type?

Tags: c#, oop, types, casting, polymorphism

I am trying to make a type which can act as a list or a dictionary or a value by itself.
Definition:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I am trying to find an alternative for `object` type which is used as the dictionary value type here.
The value type I have here is object because I can put in whatever I want.
But when I take it out I want to be able to cast it to `List<object>` or `Dictionary<string, object>` and do null checks to get the actual value.

Access:

```
foreach (string k in data.Keys)
    ParseValue(data[k], new TextWriter());
...

private void ParseValue(object value, TextWriter writer)
{
    var valList = value as List<object>;
    var valDict = value as Dictionary<string, object>;

    if (valList != null) 
        valList.ForEach(v => ParseValue(v, writer));
    else if (valDict != null) 
        valDict.Keys.ForEach(k => ParseValue(valDict[k], writer));
    else writer.WriteValue(value);
}
```

If doable then I can iterate and recurse through values in the dictionary and it gives me a very flexible nested type (similar to JSON).

The instance of the object also holds values which are useful.

I want to be able to use an `ISerializable` respecting class there.

My project is in C#, but if this is possible it should work across any strictly typed language I think.

EDIT:
I can not use `new Dictionary<string, ISerializable>();` because it doesn't support primitive value types.
Eg: I can't do the following

```
Dictionary<string, ISerializable> data = new Dictionary<string, ISerializable>();
data.Add("aa", 42);
```

Comment: *"I want to be able to use an ISerializable respecting class there."* So why not use `Dictionary<string, ISerializable>`?

Comment: So what problem do you meet with now?

Comment: The problem I have right now is that I can't be sure if the values in the dictionary are serializable or not.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this a little more I wrote a wrapper class just to catch the distinction between value types and ISerializable.

```
class MySerializable
{
    public Type type { get { return _type; } }
    private Type _type = null;
    private object o;
    private ISerializable s;


    public MySerializable(object obj)
    {
        _type = o.GetType();
        ISerializable ss = obj as ISerializable;
        if (ss != null) s = ss;
        else if (_type.IsPrimitive)
        {
            o = obj;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Can only use value types or ISerializables.");
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (o != null) return o.ToString();
        else
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, s);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will work for the problem, but I am not really happy it.
Would be great to hear if anyone has better ideas/improvements to this.

EDIT: As someone pointed out on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/95q6l9/how_to_make_a_type_behave_like_an_object_type/) the public `type` access was unsafe so restricted its access.